# How to get a list of all recent SVN commit messages?

Tags: svn, history

At times I want to revisit a change I committed to SVN a short while back, but don't recall the specific files involved or the revision number.  So I would like to see a list of recent commit messages, ideally including the files included in each commit.

I picture going to the root of my working copy and entering something like the following to see the messages and files associated with the most recent 5 commits:

```
svn log -l5 -v *
```

Unfortunately, this command requires a single target, and won't accept '*'.  I know SVN has the information I want.  Is there a simple way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use `svn log -l5 -v <URL of your repository>`. `svn info` can be used to get the root URL for the repository where your working copy is connected to.

Comment: Beautiful - Thanks!  The repository URL is the * I wanted.

Comment: Then you are in a working copy. This means that the output of `svn log` is filtered to the sub path where the wc is connected to.

Comment: You can use `'^/'` inside of a working copy as a shorthand for the repository url.

Answer (score 23):

`svn log -q -v --limit N` **inside working copy** (you have WC, isn't it?!) will show *short list* of latest N commits <strike>with commit-message</strike> (mea culpa, -q supress commit-message output) and files only

**Log output example - repo**

```
>svn log -q -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/ -l 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r33 | lazybadger | 2012-02-28 16:10:41 +0600 (Вт, 28 фев 2012)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Hello.en.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r32 | lazybadger | 2011-12-27 17:37:31 +0600 (Вт, 27 дек 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Hello.de.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.en.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r31 | lazybadger | 2011-12-27 17:29:00 +0600 (Вт, 27 дек 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Hello.de.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.en.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.fr.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r30 | lazybadger | 2011-10-19 16:23:52 +0600 (Ср, 19 окт 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r29 | lazybadger | 2011-10-19 16:18:43 +0600 (Ср, 19 окт 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Secong log for commit-messages (removed -q -v)

```
>svn log http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/ -l 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r33 | lazybadger | 2012-02-28 16:10:41 +0600 (Вт, 28 фев 2012) | 1 line

One more change
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r32 | lazybadger | 2011-12-27 17:37:31 +0600 (Вт, 27 дек 2011) | 1 line

Cleanups
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r31 | lazybadger | 2011-12-27 17:29:00 +0600 (Вт, 27 дек 2011) | 1 line

Purification
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r30 | lazybadger | 2011-10-19 16:23:52 +0600 (Ср, 19 окт 2011) | 1 line

Try fix FS #2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r29 | lazybadger | 2011-10-19 16:18:43 +0600 (Ср, 19 окт 2011) | 1 line
```

If I **checkout repo from root** and svn log in WC-rot, result will not differ at all

```
Hello>svn log -q -v -l 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r33 | lazybadger | 2012-02-28 16:10:41 +0600 (Вт, 28 фев 2012)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Hello.en.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r32 | lazybadger | 2011-12-27 17:37:31 +0600 (Вт, 27 дек 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Hello.de.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.en.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r31 | lazybadger | 2011-12-27 17:29:00 +0600 (Вт, 27 дек 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Hello.de.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.en.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.fr.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r30 | lazybadger | 2011-10-19 16:23:52 +0600 (Ср, 19 окт 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r29 | lazybadger | 2011-10-19 16:18:43 +0600 (Ср, 19 окт 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
```

Comment: I had already tried this (without the '-q'), and it only seems to report commits affecting files in the current directory, and not even the most recent changes to files in the current directory.  (I did mean copy, not directory, in my original post, btw, thanks. Now corrected.)

Comment: OK. Use URL as target as end it in repo root. I **see** file changes in repo, see my edited answer with log

Answer (score 3):

**For TortoiseSVN users:**

1. Browse to the repository folder and right click.
2. Select `TortoiseSVN` > `Show log`

The log window appears.

3. Select the first log and hold down `Shift` and select the last log you are interested in (`Ctrl` + `A` to select all. Alternatively you can use `Ctrl` selection method).
4. Right click on of the selected entries and select `Copy to clipboard` > `Messages`

The log of commit messages is copied to your clipboard.

5. Open Notepad or Notepad++ and paste the log (`Ctrl` + `v`). Save the file as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   svn log -l5 -v http://99.9.9.999/repos/reposName

   // This will show you only last 5 commit records
   ```
2. ```
   svn log -q -v http://99.9.9.999/repos/reposName

   // This will show you all the commit records
   ```